# WIA (Windows Image Acquisition). Argument Exception on CommonDialog.ShowTransfer(...)

Tags: vb.net, wia

I use WIA to acquire images using scanners.
Some users report an Argument Exception thrown by the method

```
img = dialog.ShowTransfer(_device.Items(1), WIA.FormatID.wiaFormatTIFF, False)
```

I can't reproduce the Exception on my computer with my scanner, and I couldn't find any documentation on this problem. Why is the exception raised?

I modify some device properties (such as Brightness and Resolution) in the code before calling the method, but no error is thrown in the process.

Has anyone had this problem? How would you solve it?

Comment: You are shooting off the hip by hardcoding that 1.  Kaboom when there are no suitable devices.  Not that it would make a difference, beyond your user calling somebody else :)

Comment: Maybe the program checks if device is connected before this line?